# OnDraw bug on listview

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I have created a listview with a custom onDraw method. I want to make an item of the listview appear "focused/selected" so i draw a red line on it. But on an android 2.3 phone when you scroll the listview everything created from the onDraw method suddenly appears under the textviews that the listview contains. If you touch the listview without scrolling it thus selecting an item and then release your finger the onDraw method works fine again. However on an android 4 phone enverything works ok.

This is really annoying and makes the application unusable on a 2.3 android phone.
Does anyone know why this happens? Tell me if you want me to post sample code.

Comment: Do not tell us, that we should tell you to post your code. Just post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a similar problem before and solved by using the dispatchDraw method. Add the following to your listView class:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //DO YOUR DRAWING ON UNDER THIS VIEWS CHILDREN  
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    //DO YOUR DRAWING ON TOP OF THIS VIEWS CHILDREN 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I cant vote up your answer yet but when i get enough rep i will!